# Power Query wildcard for File.content

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

Very simple, below is the source file code to pull CSV files from a folder. I want to pull files of whichever date that contain a specific text string.

For instance the file path is : C:\Users\Sebs\Desktop\Professional Clients\Tradmarket\Data\EquitiesExecuted_05-03-2019_to_05-03-2020.txt

I want to change this so it pulls only the files that have the word "EquitiesExecuted" regardless of the rest of the text string.

`Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\Sebs\Desktop\Professional Clients\Kau Markets\Data\CFDTradesExecuted_05-03-2019_to_05-03-2020.txt"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=60, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),`

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `Folder.Files` to download a table with all the files
- Then Filter (`Table.SelectRows` according to your criteria
- The `Content` column will contain a link to each file, and you can decide what you want to do with the result.  You have a number of options.

```
    Source = Folder.Files("C:\Users\Sebs\Desktop\Professional Clients\Tradmarket\Data"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each Text.Contains([Name], "EquitiesExecuted"))
```

The `Content` column will contain a link to each file, and you can explore the various options available to you.

Comment: Dear Ron,
I am new to Power Query and came across your solution above. Trying it on my side, I was confused, that even I did replace "EquitiesExecuted" with 110 for a test, instead of showing just 1 out of 4, I got all 4 files shown. 
Did I misunderstand something? The reason is, that in my destination folder, I have an excel file, which is replaced every Monday and starts with 110 and is followed by a date, therefore I would like to use the "wildcard" that each time, I connect through the power query, it will only search for 110, what am I doing wrong?
Thank you very much for your support

Comment: @Mike I suggest you create a new question, showing the code **you** are using, along with a screenshot of the results of that code; and a list of the files in that folder.  Then it may be possible to reproduce your problem and develop a solution.